# Web Add-in Icon Not Loading

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, officedev

I am developing an Office add-in that will connect to a server on the local network so clients can easily integrate into our software from the Office Suite.

But, I am having issues with getting the Icon to show up in desktop programs (it shows up fine in Office 365 [online stuff]).

Each XML file needs to be generate for each customer (since the website is on the local network--not a static domain).

Here is the generated XML for Outlook: https://gist.github.com/mwrouse/b9e1663b18d1b6830d3466acfedee20b

Am I missing something somewhere? The icons are actually on the internet (onlinedomain.com), while the rest of it is on a local server.

Add-ins are being sideloaded since we are unable to place them in the Office store.

Can anyone help me out to as why the icons are not showing up in the ribbon bar? I'm getting the default icon with the blue hexagons.

The Icon shows up in the "My Add-ins" menu, or whatever it is called in each program. However, it is just missing on the ribbon bar.

Comment: <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://onlinedomain.com/logo80x80.png" />
I get 404 on this address..

Comment: @OriEng that's because I obfuscated it. That's just a dummy url. https://wordaddin.mwrouse.com/logo80x80.png is what it is actually using.

Comment: OK I understand you . Can you share image what you see in ribbon bar?

Comment: It's the default one. It appears my Office programs are not loading the icons of ANY add-in (even ones from the store). So I have no clue now. Finally got a server up with the add-ins and tried it on other computers and the icons load...

Comment: @Michael Rouse, Are Icons loaded as expected?

Comment: @Michael Rouse, i have a same issue. Icons are not loading unless or untill takepane loads( office online). Once  takepane loading completed then refresh the web page, icons will be displayed as expected

Comment: @MichaelRouse I am having the same issue on the web it displays on the Desktop application the icon is not display, did you manage to get it to show ?